# How can I efficiently expand a factored tensor in numpy?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have a 3D tensor factored as three 2D matrices, like equation 22 in this paper: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~memisevr/pubs/pami_relational.pdf

My question is, if I want to calculate the tensor explicitly, is there a better way than this in numpy?

```
W = np.zeros((100,100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        for k in range(100):
            W[i,j,k] = np.sum([wxf[i,f]*wyf[j,f]*wzf[k,f] for f in range(100)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use [`einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for this stuff, just because it's usually the easiest to write:

```
def fast(wxf, wyf, wzf):
    return np.einsum('if,jf,kf->ijk', wxf, wyf, wzf)

def slow(wxf, wyf, wzf):
    N = len(wxf)
    W = np.zeros((N, N, N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(N):
                W[i,j,k] = np.sum([wxf[i,f]*wyf[j,f]*wzf[k,f] for f in range(N)]) 
    return W

def gen_ws(N):
    wxf = np.random.random((N,N))
    wyf = np.random.random((N,N))
    wzf = np.random.random((N,N))
    return wxf, wyf, wzf
```

gives

```
>>> ws = gen_ws(25)
>>> via_slow = slow(*ws)
>>> via_fast = fast(*ws)
>>> np.allclose(via_slow, via_fast)
True
```

and

```
>>> ws = gen_ws(100)
>>> %timeit fast(*ws)
10 loops, best of 3: 91.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example makes it very straightforward to propose a solution using `np.einsum()`:

```
W = np.einsum('ij,jf,kf->ijk', wxf, wyf, wzf)
```